# how gtest for compare an nested containers

Tags: c++, googletest

I encounter one ut, about compare nested vectors.

in old code, the ut code is below:

```
EXPECT_THAT(resources[1].cookies, ElementsAre(cookie{0}, cookie{1}, 
    cookie{constant::invalid_cookie}));
```

cookies is a vector, the cookie has one int id member, like fake code below:

```
struct cookie
{
    int id;
};
```

in new code, I have to add another vector in struct cookie; **the ut succeed. but the valgrind check failed.** failure like below:

```
==32660== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==32660==    at 0x5943BE1: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==32660==    by 0x59483AB: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1636)
==32660==    by 0x596F4CF: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:114)
==32660==    by 0x594EFBE: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==32660==    by 0x21C5BE: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintByteSegmentInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/cilom_C_PL/slaves_workspace/x86_64-0/valgrind-coverage/build/build_cov_mcu/CP_TraceController/Test/ut_stop_call_handlers)
==32660==    by 0x21C647: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintBytesInObjectToImpl(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/cilom_C_PL/slaves_workspace/x86_64-0/valgrind-coverage/build/build_cov_mcu/CP_TraceController/Test/ut_stop_call_handlers)
==32660==    by 0x21C6E9: testing::internal2::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/cilom_C_PL/slaves_workspace/x86_64-0/valgrind-coverage/build/build_cov_mcu/CP_TraceController/Test/ut_stop_call_handlers)
==32660==    by 0x19D881: testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<tc::master::detail::cookie, (testing::internal2::TypeKind)2>::PrintValue(tc::master::detail::cookie const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:140)
==32660==    by 0x19D624: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& testing::internal2::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, tc::master::detail::cookie>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, tc::master::detail::cookie const&) (gtest-printers.h:209)
==32660==    by 0x19D128: void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo<tc::master::detail::cookie>(tc::master::detail::cookie const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:250)
==32660==    by 0x19C082: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<tc::master::detail::cookie>(testing::internal::WrapPrinterType<(testing::internal::DefaultPrinterType)3>, tc::master::detail::cookie const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:445)
==32660==    by 0x19AA11: void testing::internal::PrintTo<tc::master::detail::cookie>(tc::master::detail::cookie const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:482)
==32660==    by 0x199698: testing::internal::UniversalPrinter<tc::master::detail::cookie>::Print(tc::master::detail::cookie const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:724)
==32660==    by 0x1977E9: void testing::internal::UniversalPrint<tc::master::detail::cookie>(tc::master::detail::cookie const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:873)
==32660==    by 0x194BE3: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > >(testing::internal::WrapPrinterType<(testing::internal::DefaultPrinterType)0>, std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:396)
==32660==    by 0x191357: void testing::internal::PrintTo<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > >(std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:482)
==32660==    by 0x18B8A0: testing::internal::UniversalPrinter<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > >::Print(std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:724)
==32660==    by 0x184771: void testing::internal::UniversalPrint<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > >(std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&, std::ostream*) (gtest-printers.h:873)
==32660==    by 0x17C502: bool testing::internal::MatchPrintAndExplain<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const, std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&>(std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&, testing::Matcher<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&> const&, testing::MatchResultListener*) (gmock-matchers.h:712)
==32660==    by 0x174C9F: testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::PredicateFormatterFromMatcher<testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<tc::master::detail::cookie, tc::master::detail::cookie, tc::master::detail::cookie> > >::operator()<std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > >(char const*, std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> > const&) const (gmock-matchers.h:1856)
==32660==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==32660==    at 0x4C2B25F: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==32660==    by 0x192C9D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==32660==    by 0x18E8CE: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> >::allocate(std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
==32660==    by 0x187849: std::_Vector_base<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:172)
==32660==    by 0x17E33E: std::_Vector_base<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:187)
==32660==    by 0x176E30: std::_Vector_base<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> const&) (stl_vector.h:138)
==32660==    by 0x16F1AF: std::vector<tc::master::detail::cookie, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator<tc::master::detail::cookie> const&) (stl_vector.h:284)
==32660==    by 0x16991B:
```

do the study below:
from the err print, seems gtest take the nested vector of cookie as one 8 size pointer.

1. first think the ElementsAre is not right, may be caused by the constuctor of the cookie, I add the vector.clear() to it, also failed.
2. my one Colleague, told me one another method, code change to below:

   std::vector test2;
   test2.push_back(cookie(0));
   test2.push_back(cookie(constant::invalid_cookie));
   test2.push_back(cookie(1));
   EXPECT_THAT(resources[0].cookies, ::testing::ContainerEq(test2));

also failed.

code already in the article.

is there has any matcher in gtest can apply to this situation.

Comment: How is `resources` container declared/defined/filled? Maybe `resources[0]` is indeed invalid pointer?

Comment: that resource is another vector, which ininitilished right, that is not key. and yes, that is true indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question completely, but I'll try to answer as good as possible. First of all `ElementsAre` is nestable, so in case you have something like

```
::std::vector<::std::vector<cookie>> cookie_tree;
```

it could be compared like this (given that `cookie` provides an `operator==`)

```
using ::testing::ElementsAre;
using ::testing::Eq;
EXPECT_THAT(cookie_tree, ElementsAre(
                 ElementsAre(Eq(cookie{1}), Eq(cookie{2})),
                 ElementsAre(Eq(cookie{3}), Eq(cookie{2}), Eq(cookie{1}))
            ))
```

In case `cookie` contains a member that is a `::std::vector` itself, e.g.

```
struct cookie
{
  int id;
  ::std::vector<int> elems;
};
```

you can use the `::testing::Field` matcher to match single fields, where for the vector you can choose freely how you want to compare by choosing another matcher that fits your needs. One possible way would be something like this

```
struct cookie {
    int id;
    std::vector<int> elems;
};

using ::testing::Field;
using ::testing::AllOf;
using ::testing::ElementsAre;

// in test case:
const std::vector<cookie> cookies{{1, {2, 3, 4}}, {5, {6, 7, 8}}};
EXPECT_THAT(cookies, ElementsAre(AllOf(Field("id", &cookie::id, 1),
                                       Field("elems", &cookie::elems, ElementsAre(2, 3, 4))),
                                 AllOf(Field("id", &cookie::id, 5),
                                       Field("elems", &cookie::elems, ElementsAre(6, 7, 8)))
                                 ));
```

I want to emphasize that at this point it makes sense to define own matchers, to keep the code readable, e.g.

```
auto is_cookie(const cookie& other) {
    return AllOf(Field("id", &cookie::id, other.id),
                 Field("elems", &cookie::elems, ContainerEq(other.elems)));
}
```

A full working example (e.g. in godbolt) apart from also providing nice error output would be this code snippet:

```
#include <vector>

#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using ::testing::AllOf;
using ::testing::ContainerEq;
using ::testing::ElementsAre;
using ::testing::Field;

struct cookie {
    int id;
    std::vector<int> elems;
};

bool operator==(const cookie& lhs, const cookie& rhs) {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.elems == rhs.elems;
}

auto is_cookie(const cookie& other) {
    return AllOf(Field("id", &cookie::id, other.id),
                 Field("elems", &cookie::elems, ContainerEq(other.elems)));
}

TEST(CookieTest, Something) {
   std::vector<cookie> cookies{{1, {2, 3, 4}}, {5, {6, 7, 8}}};
   EXPECT_THAT(cookies, ElementsAre(is_cookie({1, {2, 3, 4}}),
                                    is_cookie({5, {6, 7, 8}})));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```